# The Right Groups of Ahlus-Sunnah?

Tags: sunni, sects, aqidah

This particular discussion really frustrates me. I recently got into the debates about the right group of Ahlus-Sunnah. Probably I will not repeat to research these discussions again. It is just frustrating to see Maturidis, Asharis and Atharis debating whether, who is Ahlus-Sunnah and who is Ahlul-Bidah (from an Aqeedah perspective).

The question:
Are there scholars, who affirmed that all those three groups (Atharis, Maturidis, Asharis) are Ahlus-Sunnah Wal Jamaah? (meaning in the technical definition, not in the meaning of being other than Shia)

Additional thoughts:
This debate really only creates division, if is debated under laymen. Also, if we exclude one of those groups, a large percentage of the Muslim Ummah will fall under the category of Ahlul Bidah out of nowhere in opposition to this Hadith:

> And [it is reported] in al-Tirmidhi from Ibn ‘Abbas, he said: The Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him and grant him peace) said: “The hand of Allah is with the Jama‘ah.” [It is] an uncommon hadith.

So the majority of Muslims can’t be misguided in this issue. Everyone, who excludes one large group, must explain this particular point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Imam as Saffarini (a relied upon Athari scholar) has affirmed that the Atharis, Ash'aris and Maturidis are apart of Ahl-Al Sunnah:

[image]

> The Ahlus Sunnah wal Jama’ah are in three groups: the Athari whose
> Imam is Ahmad Ibn Hanbal, the Ash’ari whose Imam is Abu Hasan
> al-Ash’ari, and the Maturidi whose Imam is Abu Mansur al-Maturidi